# LTO-6 with Hardware Encryption Enabled using LTFS File System Possible on HP Ultrium?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, compression, tape, lto

I've googled this issue, but can't seem to find an answer to point me in the right direction - or if this simply is not possible.

My HP Ultrium LTO-6 Drive supports AES-256 Hardware Encryption as well as Hardware Compression.

I have no issues using the HP Cartridge Utility Software to Format the new LTO-6 Tape Cassette. Enabling Compression via Hardware, and mounting to a volume for easy access on a Windows 7 64 Bit System.

However I can't seem to find any options to enable "Hardware Encryption" in terms of password protecting my business backups.

The feature is mentioned as a supported feature in the manual, and online documentation. But I don't know what software I need, and HP's documentation on the drive is for any LTO user, very uneducating... and leaves a lot of questions to be asked.

Does anyone know if I can enable this feature using LTFS, or do I need to upgrade to a software suite and stop using LTFS to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I created a small tool for Windows, to manage encryption, that works together with LTFS.

https://github.com/VulpesSARL/LTOEnc

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also look on [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)
Since this is your tool, I suggest to include on your answer how to achieve what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how its done in windows- Ive done it in linux.

less than 10 sec to gen a 256 key, send it to the drive- seconds later- The led is lit up.

dunno if it works w LTFS. May have to do with your backup software- windows doesnt utilize the drive- but will see it. Normally I use the command line on *nix. Standalone machine w e-pci sas controller.

Plug, play- format tape- if you know what I mean. LTFS requires some "make dancing" and "slight code modifications" to work. stenc compiles ok - out of the box. standard mt-st package is needed. LSI ePci controller.

Comment: Could you please reword your answer to be a bit more specific than "if you know what I mean" etc?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the delayed response. I believe the answer is there is no simple solution to use the 6250's built in encryption feature (which is a nice feature as there is no performance hit) when operating the drive in an LTFS setup. I looked into a number of LTO Tape Library Software Setups for my Ultriums, but cost simply didn't even factor in, because the ease of use with LTFS is simply not found under any other environment. I only have 100 or so tapes, I'm not an enterprise setup, so the LTFS drag and drop, load and use, eject and put away, is best. Thanks again.